# What is the cardinality of the equivalence relation $R$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

An equivalent relation $R$ has three equivalent classes of sizes $8,10,12$.

Then the cardinality of $R$ is ?

---

Any approach for such questions ?

Comment: The equivalence classes are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the equivalence class, everyone is related to each other including itself. Also, if they are not in the same equivalent class, they are not related.

Hence $$8^2+10^2+12^2$$